# Nomad Artifact download issue

Tags: nomad

Operating system
**Windows 10**

**Working on nomad - 0.11.3
Nomad Java SDK - 0.11.3.0
Nomad runs as dev mode**

I am trying to download git repo using nomad job. But getting the error after loading the repo in job's allocation folder.

Error ::
2 errors occurred:
* failed to parse config:
* Root value must be object: The root value in a JSON-based configuration must be either a JSON object or a JSON array of objects.

#### Job file (if appropriate)

```
{
  "id": "get_git_job",
  "name": "get_git_job",
  "datacenters": [
    "dc1"
  ],
  "taskGroups": [
    {
      "name": "get_git_group",
      "tasks": [
        {
          "name": "get_git_task",
          "driver": "raw_exec",
          "resources": {
            "cpu": 500,
            "memoryMb": 2000
          },
          "artifacts": [
            {
              "getterSource": "github.com/hashicorp/nomad",
              "relativeDest": "local/repo"
            }
          ],
          "leader": false,
          "shutdownDelay": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "dispatched": false
}
```

#### Nomad Client logs (if appropriate)

```
[INFO]  client.alloc_runner.task_runner.task_hook.logmon.nomad.exe: opening fifo: alloc_id=10becf73-7abc-39c6-2114-38eea708103b task=get_git_task @module=logmon path=//./pipe/get_git_task-48748a1a.stdout timestamp=2020-12-02T16:32:33.755+0530

[DEBUG] client.alloc_runner.task_runner.task_hook.artifacts: downloading artifact: alloc_id=10becf73-7abc-39c6-2114-38eea708103b task=get_git_task artifact=github.com/hashicorp/nomad

[INFO]  client.alloc_runner.task_runner.task_hook.logmon.nomad.exe: opening fifo: alloc_id=10becf73-7abc-39c6-2114-38eea708103b task=get_git_task @module=logmon path=//./pipe/get_git_task-48748a1a.stderr timestamp=2020-12-02T16:32:33.761+0530

[DEBUG] client: updated allocations: index=518 total=25 pulled=22 filtered=3

[DEBUG] client: allocation updates: added=0 removed=0 updated=22 ignored=3

[DEBUG] client: allocation updates applied: added=0 removed=0 updated=22 ignored=3 errors=0

[DEBUG] nomad.deployments_watcher: deadline hit: deployment_id=64d58e2c-d695-27a8-3daa-134d90e10807 job="<ns: "default", id: "get_git_job">" rollback=false

[DEBUG] worker: dequeued evaluation: eval_id=0aa4f715-be9c-91de-e1ed-a1d9b41093bc

[DEBUG] worker.service_sched: reconciled current state with desired state: eval_id=0aa4f715-be9c-91de-e1ed-a1d9b41093bc job_id=get_git_job namespace=default results="Total changes: (place 0) (destructive 0) (inplace 0) (stop 0)
Desired Changes for "get_git_group": (place 0) (inplace 0) (destructive 0) (stop 0) (migrate 0) (ignore 1) (canary 0)"

[DEBUG] worker.service_sched: setting eval status: eval_id=0aa4f715-be9c-91de-e1ed-a1d9b41093bc job_id=get_git_job namespace=default status=complete

[DEBUG] worker: updated evaluation: eval="<Eval "0aa4f715-be9c-91de-e1ed-a1d9b41093bc" JobID: "get_git_job" Namespace: "default">"

[DEBUG] worker: ack evaluation: eval_id=0aa4f715-be9c-91de-e1ed-a1d9b41093bc

[WARN]  client.alloc_runner.task_runner: some environment variables not available for rendering: alloc_id=10becf73-7abc-39c6-2114-38eea708103b task=get_git_task keys=

[ERROR] client.alloc_runner.task_runner: running driver failed: alloc_id=10becf73-7abc-39c6-2114-38eea708103b task=get_git_task error="2 errors occurred:
* failed to parse config:
* Root value must be object: The root value in a JSON-based configuration must be either a JSON object or a JSON array of objects.

"
[INFO]  client.alloc_runner.task_runner: not restarting task: alloc_id=10becf73-7abc-39c6-2114-38eea708103b task=get_git_task reason="Error was unrecoverable"

[INFO]  client.gc: marking allocation for GC: alloc_id=10becf73-7abc-39c6-2114-38eea708103b

[DEBUG] nomad.client: adding evaluations for rescheduling failed allocations: num_evals=1

[DEBUG] worker: dequeued evaluation: eval_id=0490184c-d395-3e65-d38b-8dabd70b9b9d

[DEBUG] worker.service_sched: reconciled current state with desired state: eval_id=0490184c-d395-3e65-d38b-8dabd70b9b9d job_id=get_git_job namespace=default results="Total changes: (place 0) (destructive 0) (inplace 0) (stop 0)
```

anyone can help with this.

Comment: This is your error: "Root value must be object: The root value in a JSON-based configuration must be either a JSON object or a JSON array of objects." Your config is a json object though, so this is confusing. What command are you running to schedule the job?

Comment: i m not running any command, getting the git repo using Nomad Job.

Answer (score 1):

The question is resolved with the help of the Nomad team. And the solvation is that I need to add a command configuration Bcz of the driver is raw_exec.